# How to run an container with specific tag docker-py

Tags: python, docker, byte, dockerpy

Trying to run a docker container from docker-py, but when I run: 
`client.containers.run(image='my/image:tag')`

I get this error:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found

Encoding to bytes with:

`client.containers.run(image='my/image:tag'.encode())`

Gives the error:

TypeError: b'my/image:tag' is not JSON serializable

I've tried going through the run function to see if there's a tag keyword, but as far as I can tell there's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `images.list()` first and then use `get` to get the required image

**Ex:**

```
client.images.list()
#--> Should output all available Images
```

Then Run

```
container = client.images.get('Image_Name')   
container.stop()   #Stops Image.
```

This should give you exact image name.

```
container.attrs['Config']['Image']
```

Comment: Good solution, do you know why you can't pass a string? The documentation indicates that it's possible